# Can i change UITableViewCell appearance in UISearchDisplayController's searchResultsTable when it displays no results

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change UITableViewCell appearance if cellForRowAtIndexPath is not calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660942/how-to-change-uitableviewcell-appearance-if-cellforrowatindexpath-is-not-calling)

I have a table view with search display controller in my app. Table view cells have custom background color, created by pattern image. The problem is when i start to searching and there are no results, table view cells created automatically (without calling cellForRowAtIndexPath:), so i can't change their appearance. But i want all my table view cells have the same background color. So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you duplicating your earlier question?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in viewDidLoad()
`self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // set your color for tableview here`